# Can I move a subsite in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, migration

Right now our Intranet has a Home site landing page, which has five subsites. One of these sites, 'Intranet Development', has a second level HR subsite that was being worked on. It is now completed and I am tasked with moving it out from under 'Intranet Development' and onto the first level of subsites. As of now, I have not been able to accomplish this.

I tried creating a template of it and creating a new subsite using said template but once the operation is complete and I click the link to take me to the new site I get an error saying the operation could not be completed. I went back to the HR subsite and deleted all workflows in case that was the problem, but that did not change the results.

I could rebuild the site entirely but it contains 50+ documents I do no want to reupload one by one. Is there an easy way to move a subsite? If not, How can I move a document library from one site to another so that when I delete the original site the secondary one retains the documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The available option to move subsite in SharePoint Foundation is using [`Import-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)/[`Export-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  Cmdlets.

**Export-SPWeb CMDLET**

```
Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"
```

**Import-SPWeb CMDLET**

```
Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

> **Note:** You should be aware of Exporting / Importing site does not preserve workflows, unfortunately, it's one of the disadvantages of
>   the Exporting / Importing.

Comment: Where do i use those commands? Just in the normal Command Prompt or withing SharePoint Designer? I've never used the import/export function so I do not know.
Thanks

Comment: using SharePoint Management PowerShell

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with SharePoint's Content and Structure tool. It's located under Site Settings, in the Site Administration category.

Locate the HR subsite you want to move in the left tree view, then click on it to open its menu, select Move..., and select the top-level Home site to move it there.

Blog with more details: https://sharepointadam.com/2012/06/27/move-a-site-within-a-site-collection-using-content-and-structure/

Please note #1: This will change the site URL, so previous links in e-mails, local bookmarks, etc. will break. SharePoint is generally pretty good about updating links within itself when you use this tool.

Please note #2: If the site size exceeds your list view threshold, you'll get an error and need to increase that value in central admin before you can move the site. Here's a blog with more details: http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-list-view-threshold.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Content and Structure tool is not available in SharePoint Foundation !!! it requires Publishing feature!!